# Issue in Taking Mysql database backup from java

Tags: java, mysql

OK i know there are lots of questions and articles related to it,and after following them and playing with them still i can't able to succed.Here is my code

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.URISyntaxException;   
 import java.security.CodeSource;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BackupData 
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try 
    {

        /*NOTE: Getting path to the Jar file being executed*/
        /*NOTE: YourImplementingClass-> replace with the class executing the code*/
        CodeSource codeSource = BackupData.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
        File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        String jarDir = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath();
        System.out.println("jarDir"+ jarDir);


        /*NOTE: Creating Database Constraints*/
        String dbName = "xyz";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass = "root";

        /*NOTE: Creating Path Constraints for folder saving*/
        /*NOTE: Here the backup folder is created for saving inside it*/
        String folderPath = jarDir + "\\backup";

        /*NOTE: Creating Folder if it does not exist*/
        File f1 = new File(folderPath);
        System.out.println("f1" + f1);
        f1.mkdir();

        /*NOTE: Creating Path Constraints for backup saving*/
        /*NOTE: Here the backup is saved in a folder called backup with the name backup.sql*/

         String savePath = "\"" + jarDir + "\\backup\\" + "1.sql\"";
         System.out.println("savepath" + savePath);

        /*NOTE: Used to create a cmd command*/
        String executeCmd = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\\mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p " + dbPass + " --database " + dbName + " -r " + savePath;

        /*NOTE: Executing the command here*/
        Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        /*NOTE: processComplete=0 if correctly executed, will contain other values if not*/


              if (processComplete == 0) 
          {
            System.out.println("Backup Complete");
          } 

             else 
          {
            System.out.println("Backup Failure");
            System.out.println(processComplete);
          }




    } 
    catch (URISyntaxException | IOException | InterruptedException ex) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error at Backuprestore" + ex.getMessage());
    }
      }
     }
```

And the output this code is giving - Backup Failure,2(Process Complete Value)

I just can't understand what am i doing wrong?am i missing something?
I just can't able to figure out that what the problem is,any help will be appreciated,Thanks.

Comment: read the error stream to find out what is happend

Comment: there is no error stream for it,i am running it as a java application

Comment: Process has an error stream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream()

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do all this? There is a command line utility called [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) for this purpose.

> The mysqldump client utility performs logical backups, producing a set
>   of SQL statements that can be executed to reproduce the original
>   database object definitions and table data. It dumps one or more MySQL
>   databases for backup or transfer to another SQL server. The mysqldump
>   command can also generate output in CSV, other delimited text, or XML
>   format. Also you can find the following links useful from mysql
>   manual.

1. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html
2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html